# Populating a listbox in a seperate window gives me a InvalidOperationException. I'm using WPF and .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

As I was trying to learn how to use multiple windows in WPF, I stumbled upon a problem. I have a MainWindow containing all the logic for a blackjack game. Now I wanted a second Window with the last 10 games played by the user.
These last 10 games were stored in

```
public static ListBoxItem[] historiekArray = new ListBoxItem[10];
```

In the 'Speler' class (Player in Dutch). Now when I try to populate the HistoryWindow Listbox, everything goes well the first time, but the second time I open up the window this error occurs:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one.'
```

This is the C# code in the HistoryWindow.xaml.cs

```
public HistoriekWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // empty the listbox
    LbxHistoriek.Items.Clear();

    // Populate listbox with array items
    for (int i = 0; i < Speler.historiekArray.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        ListBoxItem temp = new ListBoxItem();
        temp = Speler.historiekArray[i];
        LbxHistoriek.Items.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

Looking at other posts on StackOverflow and learn.microsoft, I thought the problem might be that my ListBoxItem was being reused, but after placing `ListboxItem temp = new ListboxItem()` inside the for-loop, nothing much changed.

**SOLUTION**

The array of ListboxItems was changed into an Array of strings.

```
public static string[] historiekArray = new string[10];
```

And the for-loop sets the .Content of the ListBoxItem to the corresponding Array item.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Speler.historiekArray.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                ListBoxItem temp = new ListBoxItem();
                temp.Content = Speler.historiekArray[i];
                LbxHistoriek.Items.Add(temp);
            }
```

Please excuse my formatting, this is my first post on StackOverflow and English is not my native language.

Comment: For what statement/line do you get "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one.'" exactly?

Comment: The line where I add the temp item to the listbox.

`LbxHistoriek.Items.Add(temp);`

Comment: A listboxitem is a ui control and ui controls can only be used in just the one place. You should use the listbox items add method to add data. Template your data into ui. To show just a list of the one property you can use DisplayMemberPath. For more complicated requirements you can define an itemtemplate.

Comment: @Andy Thank you, I changed the Array of ListBoxItems to an Array of strings and then set the Content of the ListboxItems to the corresponding item in the array and it worked.